# How to show a 'X' mark on a image preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I've this upload image preview code:

```
function readURL(input) {
  $.each(input.files,function(i) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function (e) {
        var container = $('#preview_drop');
        var image = $('<img>').attr('src', e.target.result).attr('id', 'preimg')
        image.appendTo(container);
        $("#add_photoajax").mCustomScrollbar("update");
     };
     reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
  });
}
```

How can i show a '***x***' mark or a ***delete.png*** on each previewed image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 '''
 var container = $('#preview_drop');

 //Create it first
 var x = $('<img>').attr('src', 'delete.png');
 var image = $('<img>').attr('src', e.target.result).attr('id', 'preimg')
 image.appendTo(container);

 //and then append it after/before img
 x.appendTo(container);
 $("#add_photoajax").mCustomScrollbar("update");
 ...
```

Comment: Oopz,Firebug shows x.appendTo(container); is not a function.If i append it before 'image' preview doesn't shows.why this happening.I'm new to java..Plz help me to figure out this problem.

Comment: sorry, try to change `X` creation, look at my answer again.

Comment: Hehe it worked..Thank you..Is there any way to append it on right top of the 'image'

Comment: Just Use CSS buddy. Do some research about `css position`, and create new question here if you get stuck. Happy coding !

Comment: yes yes CSS will do it for me :D .I used getXYpos earlier but for some reason it didnt worked.anyways i'll use css..thanks agen dude